# How to show the show ValidationError in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-1.5

I have build a view, a template and a form, which is used in order to upload a CSV file together with some other information.

I have problems displaying the ValidationError, which I defined in my clean() function of the form:

This is part of the form:

```
class UploadCSVForm(forms.Form):

   title = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Title', required=True)

   LAYER_TYPE = (
     ('1', 'Globa;'),
   )
   layer_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LAYER_TYPE, help_text='Type of layer', required=True)

   csv = forms.FileField(required=True)

   def clean(self):

     cleaned_data = super(UploadCSVForm, self).clean()
     csv_file = self.cleaned_data.get('csv')
     if not csv_file:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("CSV must be a file."))

    return cleaned_data
```

And this is PART of my view:

```
def layer_create(request, template='layers/layer_create.html'):
....
elif request.method == 'POST':

    form = UploadCSVForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    out = {}
    if form.is_valid():
      try:
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
      except:
            ...
return render_to_response(template, RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

And this is how I render the form in the template:

```
<form id="file-uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url "layer_create" %}">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
           {{ field.help_text }} <br/>
           {{ field }} <br/>
           {{ field.errors }}<br/>
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" id="upload-button" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

The issue is that `{{ field.errors }}` don't display my ValidationError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have raised the validation in the `clean()` method, therefore that error will be stored in [`form.non_field_errors()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.non_field_errors).

If you only want to check the value of the `csv` field and assign errors to that field, then you should override `clean_csv` instead.

```
def clean_csv(self):
   csv = self.cleaned_data['csv']
   if not csv:
       raise forms.ValidationError(_("CSV must be a file."))
   return csv
```

You already have `required=True`, so I don't understand what this extra check is meant to do.

Comment: Well I know it doesn't make sense as it is but finally I want to add the option to check the format type of the file and accept only CSV.

Comment: If I use the function you provided (clean_csv) how can I access the error messages in the template? {{ field.errors }} or doesn't return anything.

Comment: If you define a `clean_csv` method, then the errors will be in `{{ field.errors }}` (when `field` is the csv field). If that doesn't display anything, then it sounds like the csv field doesn't have any errors.

Comment: You can try printing `form.errors` in your view after calling `form.is_valid()`, to see whether the form has the errors you think it does.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Though I think there must be a mistake in your code. In the if statement you kept csv_file but you dont initialize this somewhere.

Comment: It was a typo in the code - I meant to use `csv` everywhere.